# Is there a way to tell ArangoDB to rotate log files

Tags: arangodb, log-rotation

Over a long enough time the Arango log files can grow large. I do not have much access to the systems that will be running Arango, so I am hoping I can have ArangoDB rotate logfiles on some timeframe and keep some number. It looks like the arango starter can do this, but is there an option to have arangod itself rotate the logs?

I have tried looking through what arango starter changes so I can add it to my configuration file, but I think I am going in the wrong direction.